# Jsefa- Deserialize CSV with dynamic number of columns

Tags: java, csv, jsefa

Im having CSV with a dynamic number of columns, e.g.:

```
001, a ,b
002, a, b, c
003, a
```

I want to use Jsefa (or any other suggestion) to deserialize it to a class of the form:

```
@CsvDataType
public class MyCsv{
  @CsvField(pos=0)
  private String id
  //??
  private List<String> data
}
```

Does Jsefa support it?

Answer (score 1):

As the search phrase "jsefa csv dynamic number of columns" in Google returns this question as the top hit, it seems likely that the answer is "no".

I suspect this won't properly meet your requirements, and it's pretty ugly, but given that the fields are optional by default, you could do something like:

```
@CsvDataType
public class MyCsv {
  @CsvField(pos=0)
  private String id
  @CsvField(pos=1)
  private String data1
  @CsvField(pos=2)
  private String data2
  @CsvField(pos=3)
  private String data3
  @CsvField(pos=4)
  private String data4
  @CsvField(pos=5)
  private String data5
  ...
  @CsvField(pos=N)
  private String dataN
}
```

and the fields that don't have values in the CSV will just be `null`.

For a cleaner solution, I suspect you'll need to implement your own `CsvLowLevelDeserializer`, which will probably do most of the same things that `CsvLowLevelDeserializerImpl` does, but for the last field, it can look beyond the delimiter to get multiple values.

Finally, CSV is a pretty simple format to write your own parser for - depending on your needs, that might well be the most straightforward option.